# Allow user to choose only set of displayed IDs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos7

I really don't know what is this called so yea, basically I want to let the user select only the IDs shown (see pic). I'm thinking of having a variable and hold those numbers as array but I don't have any idea since I'm still learning bash scripting. Thank you!

My script goes like

```
read -p "Select accessory category below."
mysql -D snipeit -e "SELECT id AS ID, name AS Name FROM categories WHERE category_type='accessory';"
read -p "Accessory category: " accessoryCateg
if *(allow only 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 to be selected)*
*inserts data into database*
else echo "Try again!"
fi
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using

```
echo "Select accessory category below."
mysql -D snipeit -e "SELECT id AS ID, name AS Name FROM categories WHERE category_type='accessory';"
read -p "Accessory category: " userAccCateg
varAccCateg=$(mysql -D snipeit -e "SELECT id FROM categories WHERE category_type='accessory';")
accCateg=(`echo $varAccCateg | cut -d ' ' -f2-`)

if [[ " ${accCateg[@]} " =~ " ${userAccCateg} " ]]; then
    echo "You have chosen $userAccCateg"
else
    echo "Wrong choice!"
fi
```

Result is this

[image] [image]

Thanks @zhliu03 and @sjsam for helping!

Answer (score 1):

```
allowed=( $(mysql -D snipeit -e "SELECT id AS ID, name AS Name FROM categories WHERE category_type='accessory';" | awk 'NR>=4{print $2}') )

read -p "Accessory category: " accessoryCateg
for item in "${allowed[@]}"
do
  if [ "$item" -eq "$accessoryCateg" ]
  then
    #Insert Data to database
    found=1;
    break; #Don't need to continue.
  fi
done
if [ "$found" -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "Not a valid category, Please try again"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and report back if it works

Comment: @PauloBernardo : Thankyou, much appreciated

Comment: I just noticed it today, where should I really put the **done**? In your code you have 2 **done** but only 1 **do**

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the `select` command:

```
echo "Select accessory category below."
sample1=`mysql -D snipeit -e "SELECT id AS ID FROM categories WHERE category_type='accessory';"`
options=(`echo $sample1 | cut -d ' ' -f2-`)

PS3="Please select a category: "
select accessoryCateg in "${options[@]}"
do
echo "selected $accessoryCateg"
#inserts data into database
break;
done
```

Comment: Your code displays

Select accessory category below.
1) 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
Please select a category: 4
selected

Comment: oh, the line with options= ... need to change, I've edited my previous post.